# Primefaces 4.0 dataTable dialog details doesn't working

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, primefaces, datatable

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0 and Netbeans 6.9.1. I followed primefaces demo here:

[DataTable Single Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf)

Everything working fine expect button view. Here is my code:

**Customer_list.xhtml**

```xml
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
<h:form id="formTable">
    <p:dataTable styleClass="table" id="customers" var="customer" value="#{customerBean.customer}">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
            #{customer.firstName}
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
            #{customer.lastName}
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
            #{customer.email}
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">DOB</f:facet>
            #{customer.dob}
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":formCreate" oncomplete="dialogCustomerCreate.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Update">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}" target="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<h:form id="formCreate">
    <p:dialog header="Create New Customer" widgetVar="dialogCustomerCreate" resizable="false" id="dlgCustomerCreate"
              showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">

            <h:outputText value="First Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.firstName}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="Last Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.lastName}" style="font-weight:bold"/>


            <h:outputText value="Email:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.email}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="DOB:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer.dob}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

**customerBean.java**

```
public class customerBean {

    private List<Customer> customer;
    private Customer selectedCustomer;

    /** Creates a new instance of customerBean */
    public customerBean() {
        customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();        
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        CustomersDao cust_dao = new CustomersDao();
        customer = cust_dao.findAll();
        return customer;
    }

    public Customer getSelectedCustomer() {
        return selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void setSelectedCustomer(Customer selectedCustomer) {
        this.selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }
}
```

**CustomersDao.java**

```
public class CustomersDao {
    public List<Customer> findAll(){
        List<Customer> list_cust = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "FROM Customer";
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            list_cust = session.createQuery(sql).list();
            session.beginTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            session.beginTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return list_cust;
    }
}
```

Hope anyone suggest me what wrong in my code. It takes me 2 days to solve it. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you have a converter for customer class?

Comment: @fareed  i'm using Hibernate so it generated entity customer.

Comment: Try adding a converter for customer class as I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a converter for your Customer class:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Customer.class)
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.equals("") && !value.equals("0")) {
            //find and return object from DAO
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        //return object id as string
   }
}
```

Comment: I think don't need create a converter class.

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention the correct id for displaying popup dialog at `commandButton` attribute `update`.

```xml
<p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":formCreate:display" oncomplete="dialogCustomerCreate.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Update">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}" target="#{customerBean.selectedCustomer}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: move p:dialog component under p:dataTable component and update attribute id to ":formTable:display". You are used two forms, use single form.

Comment: i used multiple form for multiple purposes as well as update, delete, create.

Comment: @thehung1724 use single form once and check the problem may resolve.

Comment: @thehung1724 which server you are using for running this application

Answer (score 0):

1) Try removing your `<h:form/>`, since you're not submitting any information in that dialog;

2) Try to change your `<p:commandButton update=""/>`  to `update=":display"`;

3) Add `process="@form"` to your `<p:commandButton/>`;

4) If that works, i don't think you need that `<h:form/>`.